# Do I need to use CORS in case of RESTfull API?

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I am building a `RESTfull API` with `express`.

Is there any cases I might need to plug https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors library you can thing of? For what particular scenarios would you use `CORS` with `RESTfull API` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need CORS when the API is accessed from browsers on a website domain that is different from the API domain.  So probably, yes you need to support CORS.

You do not need CORS support if the API is not accessed from a browser.

You do not need CORS support if the API is on exactly the same domain (and port) as the website accessing the API.

Comment: Not just a different domain/host, but even a different port will require CORS.